# Are there any apps that convert max-width CSS media queries to min-width?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I sometimes want to recode responsive navigations to be mobile-first instead of having styles that adjust to smaller user devices.

Manually recoding CSS to reverse the style cascade from max-width to min-width isn't as quick as I was hoping.

Sample of CSS that could be recoded to be mobile-first: http://codepen.io/bl4ckdu5t/pen/vOBRqL

```
nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #455868;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
}
nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
}
nav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
nav a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;
}
nav li a {
    border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    background-color: #8c99a4;
}
nav a#pull {
    display: none;
}

/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav { 
        height: auto;
    }
    nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav li {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
        border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    }
    nav a {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        text-indent: 25px;
    }
}

/*Styles for screen 480px and lower*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    nav {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
        display: none;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav a#pull {
        display: block;
        background-color: #283744;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav a#pull:after {
        content:"";
        background:   url('http://s30.postimg.org/68factszx/nav_icon.png') no-repeat;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        top: 10px;
    }
}

/*Smartphone*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    nav li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know any tool that can help you with that. Here's a good article that can help you to do the changes manually: 
[link](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width)

max-width is the maximum width at which these styles will be shown. A screen wider than the specified number will not use the styles associated with that rule.

Similarly, min-width is the minimum width at which these styles will be shown. A screen narrower than the specified number will not use the styles associated with that rule.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Dagriel.  I understand the concepts of max-width and min-width,  it's just not so easy to convert CSS using one to the other without essentially recoding it from scratch.

At first glance, i thought I could just replace instances of max-width with min-width, and move the rules up or down in the cascade. But the cascading nature of CSS itself is the reason this doesn't work.